# Copying data and pasting it to specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, copy-paste

I am not being able to paste my data into specific cells in sheet2.

Like I have some data on sheet1 on the range of D:F and I want to paste it to the range of A:C on the last row. I need the code to adjust the range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(1,4,sh1.getLastRow(),3);
  rg1.copyTo(sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It worked! Though I had already figured it out but this one is better, the code is shorter!!